# Is recursion possible in a static function?

Tags: c, recursion

Is it possible to write a recursive static function in C?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? static means a funcions is local to the file.

Comment: What makes you believe it shouldn't be possible? Why not just try it out?

Comment: Why the close votes? This seems pretty straightforward to me, and I can't be the brightest person here, surely :-) Voting to reopen.

Comment: I voted to re-open. It took a little while, but it is clear what he's trying to ask.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it most certainly is. When you apply `static` to a function, it's not the same as a static variable within a recursive function (which *is* a problem if it's used in the calculations).

When applied to a function (or an object outside of a function), `static` simply controls whether that thing is visible outside the compilation unit (for the linker, for example).

When applied to an object *within* a function, `static` means that the variable exists beyond the duration of the function. In the context of a recursive function, it also means that there is only *one* copy of the variable for *all* recursion levels rather than *one per recursion level,* which is usually what's needed.

So this (what your question appears to be asking about) is perfectly okay:

```
static unsigned int fact (unsigned int n) {
    if (n == 1U) return 1;
    return n * fact (n-1);
}
```

This, on the other foot, is *not* okay, since the *single* copy of the static variable will probably be corrupted by the lower recursive layers.

```
static unsigned int fact (unsigned int n) {
    static unsigned int local_n;
    local_n = n;
    if (local_n == 1U) return 1;
    return fact (local_n - 1) * local_n;
}
```

In more detail, consider a call to `fact(3)`:

- In the first recursive layer, `local_n` is set to `3`, then a call is made to `fact(2)`.
- In the second layer, `local_n` is set to `2`, and a call is made to `fact(1)`.
- In the third layer, `local_n` is set to `1`, and we just return `1` because that's the base case of the recursion.

That's when things seem to start going wrong (although, technically, they started going wrong as soon as we typed in that `static` keyword for the `local_n` declarator):

- Back up into the second layer, we receive the `1` and multiply it by `local_n`. Now, had that variable *not* been static, it would have the (local) value of `2`. Unfortunately, it *is* static, so was set to `1` in the previous step. Hence we return `1 * 1` or, ... hang on, let me check this on the calculator ..., `1` :-)
- Ditto coming back up to the first layer, we receive the `1` and multiply it by `local_n` which, of course, still has the value `1`. So we again multiply `1 * 1` and return `1`.

If you want to try it out, here's a complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned int fact (unsigned int n) {
    static unsigned int local_n; // bad idea!
    local_n = n;
    if (local_n == 1U) return 1;
    return fact (local_n - 1) * local_n;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", fact(3));
    return 0;
}
```

That outputs the erroneous `1` but, if you get rid of the `static` keyword in the `local_n` declarator, it will return the correct `6`.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void count_to_five(void)
{
   static int i = 0;

   while (i < 5) {
     i++;
     printf("%d\n", i);
     count_to_five();
   }

  puts("You are seeing this because I counted to five! (did not enter loop)\n");    
  return;
}

int main(void)
{
    count_to_five();
    return 0;
}
```

So, yes. Note, static storage for `i` means it retains its value with each call of `count_to_five()`. However, `count_to_five()` need not be defined as `static`.

Its very hard to tell what you're asking.